# How to solve $y''-y'-y=\cos x$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Solve $y''-y'-y=\cos x$.

After first solving the homogeneous equation we know that the solution to it is $$y(x)=a\sin(x)+b\cos(x).$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used D-operators method for this.
$$y''-y'-y=\cos x\\
\implies(D^2-D-1)y=\cos x.$$
Let $$y=e^{mx}\\
\implies Dy=me^{mx}\\
\implies D^2y=m^2e^{mx}.$$
$$\therefore m^2-m-1=0\\
\implies m=\frac{1\pm\sqrt{1+4}}{2}=\frac{1\pm\sqrt{5}}{2}$$
So, C.F.=$c_1e^{\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)x}+c_2e^{\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)x}$
$$\begin{align}\\
P.I. &=\frac{\cos x}{D^2-D-1}\\
& =\frac{\cos x}{-1-D-1}\\
& =\frac{\cos x}{-D-2}\\
& =-\frac{\cos x}{D+2}\\
& =-\frac{\cos x(D-2)}{D^2-4}\\
& =-\frac{\cos x}{-1-4}(D-2)\\
& =\frac{1}{5}\cos x(D-2)\\
& =\frac{1}{5}(-\sin x-2\cos x)\\
\end{align}$$
Hence,the solution is:
$$y=\text{C.F.+P.I.}$$

Answer (score 2):

$$y''-y'-y=\cos x$$
The characteristic polynomial is:
$$\implies r^2-r-1=0$$
$$r=\dfrac {1\pm \sqrt 5}2$$
Therefore the solution to the homogeneous equation is:
$$y=e^{x/2}(c_1e^{\sqrt 5 x}+c_2e^{-\sqrt 5 x})$$
The guess for the particular solution is
$$y_p=a \cos x+ b\sin x$$

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**
Propose a particular solution $y_p(x) = Ax\cos x + Bx\sin x$ and compute $A,B$ by plugging into the ODE.